# How to force oracle to do cascade delete without dropping/recreating constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, cascade

I've got a parent table, which has a dozen child tables referencing it.
Those child tables in turn have other child tables referencing them. And so on.

I need to delete a row from the main parent table cascading it all the way down.

Dropping/recreating constraints all over the place to have them "ON CASCADE DELETE" is not an option

Going through all of them and deleting child rows manually is a nightmare.

Any other options?

Comment: are triggers a valid option for you?

Comment: @danihp, no they are not. I can't modify the schema

Comment: How many rows do you have to delete, and will this be a regular task?

Comment: @WolfgangFleischmann, I don't even know how many. This is one off task, just need to test an unusual scenario.

Comment: Do you know the `DELETE FROM (SELECT pid, cid, gid FROM myparent JOIN mychild USING (pid) JOIN mygrandchild USING (cid)) WHERE pid=xxx` Syntax? That would arguably be the most painless way to delete the rows. I can elaborate if you want...

Answer (score 29):

The DELETE statement has no parameters to make it cascading.

So you can either make user of `ON CASCADE DELETE` or just execute a bunch of separate deletes in the right order.

You could write a 'smart delete' procedure which investigates table structure and generates a series of deletes bases on that, but that will likely be more work and more of a nightmare than writing the separate deletes. And you'd *have* to have those constraints for this to work, which in reality is not always desired.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this kind of problem in oracle with an application I've done on purpose to merge data from one branch to other one - target, and then delete the source one.

https://sites.google.com/site/keytreechanger/Home
https://sites.google.com/site/keytreechanger/Home/screenshots

quoting

> Given this error, for example:
>   client Pedrus Root (internal key representation  #R=111) is the same as Petrus Root (#R=222).
>   Move data under 222 to 111, and then delete 222 branch.
>   KTC gathers all data relative to this case  (and the next few cases to be solved), in a smarty way  from all relevant tables of database.
>   The algorithm only searches where needed and using all available key components.
>   A backup of all data is locally maintained for audit purposes. The local repository evolves transparently to accommodate changes in table/field definitions.
>
> The power user visually inspects the table/relation tree, and can view/print/edit data in any table and optionally modify the presumed action (cut, or cut and paste or done).
>   Finally KTC generates hundreds of lines of inserts, updates and deletes of corrective code to solve this particular case, listed in a suitable order ending with
>       delete from rootTable where #R=222.
>   Then, I apply the code with the users online.

In your situation a filter will have to remove all lines but the delete ones.

AFAIK there is no equivalent application in the market.